# Allow character { to save to database using EF Core's ExecuteSqlRaw

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I want to allow character `{` to save to database using EF Core's `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw()`.

Basically I want to run this query successfully

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Insert into tbl(col1), values('this is a test {and I want success}')")
```

There can be many (up to hundreds) of these `{` characters - not just one or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace { with {{ and this will solve the problem. in my case it work in that way

Answer (score 2):

You can either just escape it:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Insert into tbl(col1), values('this is a test \{and I want success\}')")
```

Or, ideally, properly use parameters:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    "Insert into tbl(col1), values(@TheValue)",
    new SqlParameter("@TheValue", "this is a test {and I want success}"
);
```

Comment: Yes escape also works but if I replace { with {{ then this also works